# Microsoft Edge: selecting option forces reload

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

I am facing a really strange problem in Edge 12. When selecting an option in a dropdown and setting the cursor to an following input field the browser reloads by itself. There is no JavaScript involved. See the pen or code below.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNmVGL

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie ie6 lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie ie7 lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie ie8 lt-ie10 lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>    <html class="no-js ie ie9 lt-ie10" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
 <title>Test</title>    
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="http://localhost/ms-vouchers/sticker/step2" id="sticker-form">
        <select name="sticker_country" id="sticker-country">
            <option value="none">Land wählen ...</option>
            <option value="de">Deutschland</option>
            <option value="ch">Schweiz</option>
            <option value="at">Österreich</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="sticker_shortname" id="sticker-shortname" maxlength="3" placeholder="Kürzel" />
        <input type="text" name="sticker_name" id="sticker-name" maxlength="12" placeholder="Name" />
        <input type="submit" value="Weiter" name="proceed" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI Edge is called Microsoft Edge. It's not IE Edge; Internet Explorer is a different browser altogether.

Comment: Yes, as I have written it.

Comment: I am seeing this in version `16.16299`. There is a thread about the issue [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9828396/).

Answer (score 0):

I did a search here : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/

There are no issue related to this.

I tried on EdgeHTML version 13.10586 and I don't have this.

So if there was any error, it has been corrected.

Comment: It occurs in Edge 12.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by setting a `max` value for 100 years in the future, `2118-12-31`. There is a thread about the issue [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9828396/). I was on Edge version `16.16299`